# iOS Podfile issue with OverlayContainer from ADOverlayContainer

Tags: ios, github

I'm attempting to load the following github repository through Pods:

https://github.com/applidium/ADOverlayContainer

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `OverlayContainer`
```

Also tried 'ADOverlayContainer'.

The podfile, note the other two pods work:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.1'

target 'MyCoreData' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'SwiftCharts', '~> 0.6.3'
  pod 'SwiftGraph'
  pod 'OverlayContainer'

  # Pods for MyCoreData

  target 'MyCoreDataTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyCoreDataUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Doesn't seem to find the specified spec and the author doesn't have contact information or issues tab. Am I able to determine the correct reference somehow? The Podfile on the github repo appears to be the same reference.

Comment: Can you share your whole podfile?

Comment: Yes, added. Note the other pods are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried using your podfile in a sample project. Seems good. I successfully installed `OverlayContainer`. You could try your podfile too in a new sample project, if it doesn't work too, then the problem should be in your local pod settings.

There are multiple ways to solve that.

1. Run `pod setup` (this may take time).
2. Update your Cocoapod stuff (gem? ruby? and whatnot).
3. You could also try adding `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` in your podfile.

I hope this helps.